# Run command in Docker Container only on the first start

Tags: docker

I have a Docker Image which uses a Script (`/bin/bash /init.sh`) as Entrypoint. I would like to execute this script only on the first start of a container. It should be omitted when the containers is restarted or started again after a crash of the docker daemon.

Is there any way to do this with docker itself, or do if have to implement some kind of check in the script?

Answer (score 49):

I had the same issue, here a simple procedure (i.e. workaround) to solve it:

**Step 1:**

Create a "myStartupScript.sh" script that contains this code:

```
CONTAINER_ALREADY_STARTED="CONTAINER_ALREADY_STARTED_PLACEHOLDER"
if [ ! -e $CONTAINER_ALREADY_STARTED ]; then
    touch $CONTAINER_ALREADY_STARTED
    echo "-- First container startup --"
    # YOUR_JUST_ONCE_LOGIC_HERE
else
    echo "-- Not first container startup --"
fi
```

**Step 2:**

Replace the line "# YOUR_JUST_ONCE_LOGIC_HERE" with the code you want to be  executed only the first time the container is started

**Step 3:**

Set the scritpt as entrypoint of your Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/myStartupScript.sh"]
```

In summary, the logic is quite simple, it checks if a specific file is present in the filesystem; if not, it creates it and executes your just-once code. The next time you start your container the file is in the filesystem so the code is not executed.

Comment: Seems right on the first go. But when I prune my containers using "docker container prune", I would expect the startup script to run again. That is not happening.

Comment: @KranthiKiranP The "CONTAINER_ALREADY_STARTED" file is saved on the container filesystem, so if the container uses a volume, the file could be in the volume. Purging the volumes should fix your issue.

Comment: I used this approach, and for a test, if the container was initialized I'm checking if there's specific file in /tmp direcotry like:

if [ ! -f /tmp/foo.txt ]; then
    echo "File not found!"
else
    echo "File found!"
fi. So @KranthiKiranP it wil cover your case.

Answer (score 13):

The entry point for a docker container tells the docker daemon what to run when you want to "run" that specific container. Let's ask the questions "what the container should run when it's started the second time?" or "what the container should run after being rebooted?"

Probably, what you are doing is following the same approach you do with  "old-school" provisioning mechanisms. Your script is "installing" the needed scripts and you will run your app as a systemd/upstart service, right? If you are doing that, you should change that into a more "dockerized" definition.

The entry point for that container should be a script that actually launches your app instead of setting things up. Let's say that you need  java installed to be able to run your app. So in the dockerfile you set up the base container to install all the things you need like:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk --update upgrade && apk add openjdk8-jre-base
RUN mkdir -p /opt/your_app/ && adduser -HD userapp

ADD target/your_app.jar /opt/your_app/your-app.jar
ADD scripts/init.sh /opt/your_app/init.sh

USER userapp
EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/your_app/init.sh"]
```

Our containers, at the company I work for, before running the actual app in the init.sh script they fetch the configs from consul (instead of providing a mount point and place the configs inside the host or embedded them into the container). So the script will look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Downloading config from consul..."
confd -onetime -backend consul -node $CONSUL_URL -prefix /cfgs/$CONSUL_APP/$CONSUL_ENV_NAME
echo "Launching your-app..."
java -jar /opt/your_app/your-app.jar
```

One advice I can give you is (in my really short experience working with containers) treat your containers as if they were stateless once they are provisioned (all the commands you run before the entry point).

Comment: Completely agree on considering containers stateless. If there's data to initialize, place it in a volume.

Comment: I'd really like to follow your advice, but it's not that easy. I have very little influence on changes of the app and there had to be changed A LOT to use it the way you described. For example: every time a container starts, the init script sets up a database for the app. This should not happen when the container is restarted, because it overwrites the data that is already there ...
Unfortunately it proofed to be very hard to teach the developers of the app how to use docker. So I am trying to keep it extremely simple for them.

Comment: how do you run this?

Comment: Could you provide an *answer* and then explain why it is a bad practice and let people decide if they want it or not? I want to run some cli commands to setup data for unit tests and this question looks exactly like what I want. But your not an answer doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 12):

I had to do this and I ended up doing a `docker run -d` which just created a detached container and started `bash` (in the background) followed by a `docker exec`, that did the necessary initialization. here's an example

```
docker run -itd --name=myContainer myImage /bin/bash
docker exec -it myContainer /bin/bash -c /init.sh
```

Now when I restart my container I can just do

```
docker start myContainer
docker attach myContainer
```

This may not be ideal but work fine for me.

Comment: This is actually the best way to approach the situation. You start your container as a stateless container, and then you just make it run once the initialization command, that might do a host of things, like mine for example runs all the database migrations that are pending. I wouldn't really see the point of having a container just to run migrations.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same on windows container. It can be achieved using task scheduler on windows. Linux equivalent for task Scheduler is cron. You can use that in your case. To do this edit the dockerfile and add the following line at the end

```
WORKDIR /app 
COPY myTask.ps1 . 
RUN schtasks /Create /TN myTask /SC ONSTART /TR "c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe C:\app\myTask.ps1" /ru SYSTEM
```

This Creates a task with name myTask runs it ONSTART and the task its self is to execute a powershell script placed at "c:\app\myTask.ps1".

This myTask.ps1 script will do whatever Initialization you need to do on the container startup. Make sure you delete this task once it is executed successfully or else it will run at every startup. To delete it you can use the following command at the end of myTask.ps1 script.

```
schtasks /Delete /TN myTask /F
```

Comment: [How to run a cron job only once](https://serverfault.com/a/111656/85654)