# How to Initialize a Collection in Dockerized Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

Here below is the `docker-compose.yml` I use to dockerize my MongoDB instance:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - 'data-storage:/data/db'
    networks:
      mynet:

volumes:
  data-storage:

networks:
  mynet:
```

The container is created correctly and it starts without any problem. Is it possible to create a Mongo collection and populate it with some documents the first time the container starts?

For instance, I'd like to run a few statements like these:

```
db.strategyitems.insert( { symbol: "chf", eval_period: 15, buy_booster: 8.0, sell_booster: 5.0, buy_lot: 0.2, sell_lot: 0.2 } )
db.strategyitems.insert( { symbol: "eur", eval_period: 15, buy_booster: 8.0, sell_booster: 5.0, buy_lot: 0.2, sell_lot: 0.2 } )
db.strategyitems.insert( { symbol: "usd", eval_period: 15, buy_booster: 8.0, sell_booster: 5.0, buy_lot: 0.2, sell_lot: 0.2 } )
```

...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command in Docker Container only on the first start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836764/run-command-in-docker-container-only-on-the-first-start)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [MongoDB docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/), you can use this combination to init your db :
Environnement variable MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE

> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used
> for creation scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js (see
> Initializing a fresh instance below). MongoDB is fundamentally
> designed for "create on first use", so if you do not insert data with
> your JavaScript files, then no database is created.

And init .js files in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

> Initializing a fresh instance
>
> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
> with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
> order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
> specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
> test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

Note that you can skip setting environnement variable, and set your database in js file. See [the doc for more explanations.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/mongo#initializing-a-fresh-instance) environment variable in your `docker-compose` file to specify the database name to use, and add your  [`db.createCollection()`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) command(s) to a `.js` file.

---

```
my-app-directory
├── docker-compose.yml
└── init-mongo-db-with-collections.js
```

---

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: xxx
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: my-db
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo-db-with-collections.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo-db-with-collections.js:ro
```

`init-mongo-db-with-collections.js`

```bash
db.createCollection("my-empty-collection")
db.strategyitems.insert( { symbol: "chf", eval_period: 15, buy_booster: 8.0, sell_booster: 5.0, buy_lot: 0.2, sell_lot: 0.2 } )
...
```

---

```
my-db
└── collections
    ├── my-empty-collection
    └── `strategyitems`
        └── { symbol: "chf", eval_period: 15, buy_booster: 8.0, sell_booster: 5.0, buy_lot: 0.2, sell_lot: 0.2 }
```