# Problem to auto create database/table in Docker with MongoDB/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, docker

I'm new in docker, so cant understand - if I want to build automatically container of mongoDB - how to create database and schema of database/table automatiacally? Maybe in Dockerfile or i can do it from docker-compose.yml?

I mean, if there's is automatically so, that's dont need to use the queries like CREATE TABLE, CREATE DATABASE.

There is my code:
SERVER.JS

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const requireDir = require("require-dir");

//Iniciando o App
const app = express();

//Iniciando o DB
const mongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeapi', {useUnifiedTopology: true});

requireDir("./src/models");

const Product = mongoose.model('Product');

//Primeira rota
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Product.create({
        title: 'React Native',
        description: 'Build native apps with React',
        url: 'http://github.com/facebook/react-native'
    });

    return res.send("hello word 1");

});

app.listen(3001);
```

PRODUCT.JS

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

      title:{
          type: String,
          required: true,
      },
      description: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
      },
      url: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
    },
      createdAt: {
          type: Date,
          default: Date.now,
      },
  });
 
   mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer has some good tips - [How to Initialize a Collection in Dockerized Mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662531/how-to-initialize-a-collection-in-dockerized-mongo-db/51666537) - including how to initialize a a fresh instance, and a link to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/ to make a script to initialize your database/collection.