# docker container build requires another container to run

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, fixtures

I have two docker container: One for the *backend API* and one for the *Postgres Db*.
Since this is for the test environment the DB should be filled with fixtures. The fixtures are created in such a way that the backend runs a service that fills the Db with the needed fixtures.

Is there a way to ensure the Postgres API is built and run and then the backend API is built and run?

We are using docker-compose. I know there is "depends" but what I found it is only for running the containers and not building them.

I know the process is not optimal and one should keep containers stateless but it is what I have to work with.

I found [Run command in Docker Container only on the first start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836764/run-command-in-docker-container-only-on-the-first-start).

But maybe there is another way today?

Comment: I've successfully used `wait-for-it` whenever I needed the server to be up before having the client doing anything. You might find [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) page useful.

Comment: Do you have to run tests as part of producing a Docker artifact?  Do you need PostgreSQL to run tests (or can you mock your database accessors, or use something lighter-weight like SQLite instead)?