# Only run docker container once to populate database

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a database running in docker and another container that runs a script to populate the database:

```yaml
stock-trading-system-db:
    container_name: stock-trading-system-db
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes: 
      - ./mongo/data:/data/db
  mongo_seed:
    image: mongo
    links:
      - stock-trading-system-db
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-seed:/mongo-seed
    command:
      mongo-seed/import.sh
```

I don't want to populate the database every time I launch the containers, how do I make it so it runs the script once and never again?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836764/run-command-in-docker-container-only-on-the-first-start) approach containing a startup script which could check inside MongoDB if it was already seeded or not inside your "mongo_seed" service.